# How do I get a simple list of absolute directories containing a file of a specific name?

Tags: powershell-4.0

I have been looking around for this seemingly simple answer but finding nothing applicable.   I have a file named "foo.txt" which might be found in multiple locations on my C drive.   How do I form a PS command that results in a list of lines which contain *only the full directories* (not the file name itself).  This would be a very simple matter in a Unix Bash shell but I cannot see it in PS.  The closest I could get was the following:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Filter foo.txt
```

But the format of the output is not what I am looking for. I would like the output to be a simple one-directory-per-line output of the absolute directories which contain a "foo.txt" file (not just the lowest directory).

Answer (score 1):

I found the format that I was looking for:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Filter foo.txt | Format-Table Directory -AutoSize  -HideTableHeaders
```

`Format-Table` is the secret sauce, it appears.  Without `-AutoSize` it clips long paths and adds three periods.